# js video player in Sitecore only plays the first video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, sitecore

I'm not able to get my video player to play more than the first video. I have some html and an if/else if/else block that takes the id of each link and, upon each click event, replaces the old iframe with a new one. When I click each link, the browser jumps to the top of the page.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="videoPlayer">
        <div class="video">
            <iframe width="498" height="280" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ANewBhf60pM?modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="videoLinkWrapper">
            <span>Videos:</span>
            <a id="video1" class="videoLinks buttonPrimarySmall active" title="Video #1" href="#">1</a>
            <a id="video2" class="videoLinks buttonPrimarySmall" title="Video #2" href="#">2</a>
            <a id="video3" class="videoLinks buttonPrimarySmall" title="Video #3" href="#">3</a>
            <a id="video4" class="videoLinks buttonPrimarySmall" title="Video #4" href="#">4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.videoLinks').click(function(e){
            $('.videoLinkWrapper a').removeClass('active');

            if(e.target.id=='video2'){
                 $('.contentPad30 .video iframe').replaceWith('<iframe width="498" height="280" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/gh_hOwRftbo?modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
                $('a#video2').addClass('active');
            }
            else if(e.target.id=='video3'){

                 $('.contentPad30 .video iframe').replaceWith('<iframe width="498" height="280" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/EcJ0yvCSvqA?modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
                $('a#video3').addClass('active');
            }
            else if(e.target.id=='video4'){

                 $('.contentPad30 .video iframe').replaceWith('<iframe width="498" height="280" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/S9AZSxFsch4?modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
                 $('a#video4').addClass('active');
            }
            else {
                 $('.contentPad30 .video iframe').replaceWith('<iframe width="498" height="280" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ANewBhf60pM?modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
                $('a#video1').addClass('active');
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try replacing .contentPad30 with .videoLinks

Here is the working JS fiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.videoLinks').click(function(e){
            $('.videoLinkWrapper a').removeClass('active');

            if(e.target.id=='video2'){
              $('.videoPlayer .video iframe').attr('src','//www.youtube.com/embed/gh_hOwRftbo?modestbranding=1');
                 
                $('a#video2').addClass('active');
            }
            else if(e.target.id=='video3'){

                 $('.videoPlayer .video iframe').attr('src','//www.youtube.com/embed/EcJ0yvCSvqA?modestbranding=1');
                $('a#video3').addClass('active');
            }
            else if(e.target.id=='video4'){

                 $('.videoPlayer .video iframe').attr('src','//www.youtube.com/embed/S9AZSxFsch4?modestbranding=1');
                
                 $('a#video4').addClass('active');
            }
            else {
                 $('.videoPlayer .video iframe').attr('src','//www.youtube.com/embed/ANewBhf60pM?modestbranding=1');
                $('a#video1').addClass('active');
            }
        }); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="videoPlayer">
        <div class="video">
            <iframe width="498" height="280" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ANewBhf60pM?modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="videoLinkWrapper">
            <span>Videos:</span>
            <a id="video1" class="videoLinks buttonPrimarySmall active" title="Video #1" href="#">1</a>
            <a id="video2" class="videoLinks buttonPrimarySmall" title="Video #2" href="#">2</a>
            <a id="video3" class="videoLinks buttonPrimarySmall" title="Video #3" href="#">3</a>
            <a id="video4" class="videoLinks buttonPrimarySmall" title="Video #4" href="#">4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have changed the code to change src now. Try it

Comment: Thanks for your attempt! Indeed, this does work. But the browser jump to the top of the page still happens each time I click on a link. Why is that?

Comment: You are removing an I frame and inserting it. Right?

Comment: Try replacing only the src. Then it won't happen